# Simple way to create text overlay w/ color and other options [Blender Video Editing Mode]

Tags: video-sequence-editor, text-object

Instead of going to the 3D Modeling Mode, creating a text, rendering it, and importing it into the sequence, is there a quick way to create a transparent background text overlay?

EDIT : I have seen the subtitle solution in Add>Effect Strip>Text but it does not give me the option for things like color, outline, and other options of that sort.